# How do I get a printer to work on the new MacBook Air M1?

Tags: printing, apple-silicon

I'm trying to print from my new MacBook Air M1 running Mac OS Big Sur 11.0.1 (20B29).

I have a Dymo LabelWriter Twin Turbo.

I downloaded DYMO Label™ v8.7.5, its read me includes "Support for MacOS 11 Big Sur". I installed it and added the printer in System Preferences: Printers & Scanners. I opened the DYMO Label and tried to print a label. Nothing printed.

The System Preferences: Printers & Scanners shows a yellow dot and Error (see below).

[image: System Preferences: Printers & Scanners]

Tapping on the Open Print Queue... button does nothing.

- Restart computer, no printing.
- Unplug and reconnect printer, no printing. Printer is connected by USB to CalDigit Thunderbolt 3 dock.
- Check printer feed, printer will feed labels when the hardware button on the printer is pressed.

Printing from AirPrint connected Canon MX920 *does* work. However, tapping on the Open Print Queue... button for that printer also does nothing.

I have contacted [Dymo Support](https://www.dymo.com/en-US/online-support/online-support-contact-us), but have nothing but the automatic email back from them yet.

Has anyone gotten a Dymo printer to work with the new M1 laptops?

Comment: Dymo are notoriously not printers, but devices that need custom software that’s pretty intrusive installed to translate. Are you open to an answer to say ask the printer vendor why their hardware doesn’t function at a bare minimum using AirPrint drivers so it’s clear if the OS is working.

Comment: I’m editing your second yes/no question since of course people can open print queues on Big Sur. Imagine no one being able to print since June when public BigSur betas started rolling out...

Comment: @bmike that actually is a problem that occurs specifically on m1 macs. At least with the Dymo printers. Please don't just assume that a problem doesn't exist. [@kevco's](https://apple.stackexchange.com/a/408787/411157) answer solves the problem with print queue no opening.

Comment: Are you saying the accepted answer is wrong @Sharud ? The comment is one of moderation where we require one clear question per question. If there is an issue opening an app, lets ask that question clearly. If there’s a problem printing to an installed printer, let’s ask that question. It’s two separate “problems” so I encourage you or anyone to ask that second question so people can find it and collaborate on the best solution to the other problem.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Had the same problem with a LabelWriter 450 and had previously called dymo who were aware of the issue.  Was fixed after installing macOS 11.1 without needing to further update my Dymo drivers or software.

Comment: Yes, just upgraded to 11.1 and the printer works now. Thanks.

Answer (score 4):

To resolve the "Open Print Queue" button not working, go to ~/Library/Printers and set each printer to "Open using Rosetta" on the "Get Info" screen.  This resolved the problem on both of the printers configured on my M1 MacBook Air.

Comment: Is this step needed after Apple shipped the 11.1 update?

Comment: 11.2 resolved it for me but others have reported that they still have the issue even after 11.2.3.

Answer (score 2):

If you open the spooler you will see an error “Missing USB class driver”. Apparently it’s the way the M1 handles hardware attached to USB. That’s why the printer on AirPrint worked. I’ve heard that Dymo knows about the issue but have no timeframe for a fix or if it will be even addressed.

Comment: Thanks so much for the details. Did an update to 11.1 fix this for you?

Answer (score 0):

That works for me, too. Installing drivers for HP Photosmart Wireless B109n-z

I had to install Apple's HP printer drivers, because I'm newly setting up a very old printer. Can't get it to connect to our wireless network, so I'm having to use USB.

Then set up the printer with the USB drivers. It creates a printer device in ~/Library/Printers.

Then configure the print queue to open in Rosetta. [I guess the low level USB drivers aren't available to the M1 code yet].

And then I had to reboot before they would work.